# Cannot log in to active directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having a great trouble here. We are working on a research project in which we need SharePoint 2013. Therefore, we used a cloud environment and booted up three machines and installed Active directory, SQL Server and SharePoint. Each machine had two NIC, one for internal connection between the VMs and one for remoting to those VMs.

Everything was working fine (we left the project untouched for one month because of other business).

Once I logged into the server after one month, I realized that non of the servers could ping AD server, nor AD server pinged the two other servers. I checked the connections and IPs and realized that the IP addresses of the NICs of the AD server are displaced. (i.e. in vcloud director I realized that the internal NIC has an IP in the range of 10.0.0.X while it should be set for external NIC.)

Anyway, I made a very rapid decision and changed IP addresses of AD server on both NICs. as soon as I did this the AD server was out of access and after rebooting it, I could not log in to it. The domain administrator won't log in with the following error:

> The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.
>   While the local administrator account won't log in with the "wrong password" error.

I can boot and log in to safe mode, where AD service is not running.

Is there anything I could do to bring back the AD server or re-installing everything from scratch is the only solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention: the name of AD server has changed too. It was "server-1" in the beginning but I changed it to "ad-server" before installing AD. now it is "server-1" again!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comment, it looks like renaming your AD server was the cause.

If you have access to AD through some way, try [the steps in this article.](https://virtualcurtis.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/fix-the-security-database-on-the-server-does-not-have-a-computer-account-for-this-workstation-trust-relationship/)

> - Open up Active Directory Users & Computers pointed to the domain the computer account resides in
> - From the “View” pull-down menu, make sure that “Advanced Features” is checked
> - Navigate to the part of your organizational unit (OU) structure where the computer account for this server resides
> - Open the Properties for the computer object
> - Choose the “Attribute Editor” tab on the Properties dialog box
> - Check the Attributes dNSHostName & servicePrincipalName – anywhere that a fully qualified hostname is specified (e.g. myserver.mydomainname.com), make sure that the entry matches the hostname you have configured when you go here on your server: Start -> Computer -> Right-Click, Properties -> Change Settings (under “Computer name, domain… settings”) -> Full Computer Name

Otherwise you could try changing the [name back.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794951%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for replying. the problem is I cannot log in to Active directory server, so I do not have access to Active Directory Users & Computers! Yet I will try renaming the AD server using command line which I can access using psexec.

Comment: Renaming did not work!

Comment: You might have to [remove the old SPN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015518) However I've never had to troubleshoot this far before, so perhaps someone else will be able to help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the command "setspn.exe -x", but there was no duplicate SPN.